# Google Maps V3: Infowindows not resizing to fit information

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

**Problem**

I have a API V3 map, with a content window for each marker. The content of the infowindow stretches across multiple lines, but the infowindow does not resize to fit it all, causing an iframe-like scroll to appear.

I have looked at the setContent() method in the API which according to some posts on the API V3 mailing list should correct the issue. However, it looks like I've been putting into the wrong place thus causing the map not to load.

Infowindow content is populated from a field in the locations_array.

**Map code**

Here's the code I'm using, minus the setContent() method.

```
<script src="/_global/assets/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Google Maps
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-26.66, 122.25),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    // Create an array to hold a series of generic objects
    // Each one will represent an individual marker, and contain all the
    // information we need for that marker. This way, we can reuse the data
    // on the client-side in other scripts as well.

    var locations_array = [
    {latitude: -35.015672, longitude: 117.879639, title: "Albany", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Albany</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcAlbany\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.351479, longitude: 115.666658, title: "Bunbury", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Bunbury</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcBunbury\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -24.850919, longitude: 113.731984, title: "Carnarvon", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Carnarvon</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcCarnarvon\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.361363, longitude: 116.161534, title: "Collie", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Collie</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcCollie\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.847418, longitude: 121.884107, title: "Esperance", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Esperance</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcEsperance\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -31.795396, longitude: 115.88941, title: "Gnangara", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Gnangara</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcGnangara\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.082093, longitude: 115.913902, title: "Harvey", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Harvey</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcHarvey\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.082093, longitude: 115.913902, title: "Harvey Mill", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Harvey Mill</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcHarveyMill\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -30.749071, longitude: 121.472324, title: "Kalgoorlie", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Kalgoorlie</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcKalgoorlie\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.691176, longitude: 117.557189, title: "Katanning", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Katanning</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcKatanning\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -32.531789, longitude: 115.721341, title: "Mandurah", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Mandurah</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcMandurah\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -34.250365, longitude: 116.147165, title: "Manjimup", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Manjimup</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcManjimup\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -33.982459, longitude: 115.765361, title: "Nannup", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Nannup</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcNannup\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -31.953472, longitude: 115.914248, title: "Rivervale", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Rivervale</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcRivervale\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -31.948893, longitude: 115.795029, title: "Shenton Park", infoWindowContent: "<strong>Shenton Park</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcShentonPark\">Get office details</a>"},
    {latitude: -34.214112, longitude: 116.074472, title: "West Manjimup", infoWindowContent: "<strong>West Manjimup</strong><br /><br /><a href=\"/corporate/staff_directory/phonedir.asp?loc=fpcManjimupWest\">Get office details</a>"},
    ];

    // Now let's create some markers

    for (var x = 0; x < locations_array.length; x++) {
        // Grab an individual park object out of our array
        var _park = locations_array[x];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations_array[x].latitude,locations_array[x].longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myLatlng,
            title: locations_array[x].title,
            icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/park.png',
            clickable: true,
            infocontent: locations_array[x].infoWindowContent
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: this.infocontent
            });
            infowindow.open(map,this);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
        map.setZoom(16);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I see this as well. I'm sure in maps v2 it would resize for you, but now doesn't seem to. Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the html strings of infoWindowContent in a div with a class that has a width set then change:

```
 content: this.infocontent
```

to be

```
 content: $(this.infocontent)[0]
```

Comment: This didn't help me, however my #map-window was to low (200px), I changed it to 220px and my info-window re-sized properly.